# Bundle provision profile in Mac App

Tags: macos, codesign

I created a Mac app using Qt and Network Extension framework for VPN connection (ikev2). From Apple's Developer profile page, I enabled personal VPN in provision profile. The provisioning profile is then bundled into app under: Contents/embedded.provisionprofile. I signed the app bundle with entitlement.

After downloading the app to a new Mac, gatekeeper prevented the app from running with an error message as:

code signature invalid for /Application/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp ...

In Finder, right click the app, Show package contents, then double click embedded.provisionprofile, Finder will prompt to install the profile. After provision profile is installed, the app can be open and run without error. So it appears that it is not code signature error. Rather it is an error that gatekeeper didn't find provisioning profile in the bundle, and insisted the profile must be present on the computer when it tries to open the app.

So my question is, what is the correct way to embed provisioning profile into an app and sign it, so the app can be opened without a separate step to install provision profile?

Another note: I distribute the app through a web server, not through Apple Store, and sign the app using Developer ID. Also, if I sign the app with entitlement but without embedded.provisionprofile, I got a different error when tried to run the app: Unsatisfied Entitlement. So adding embedded.provisionprofile overcame that error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are renaming the file that you downloaded instead of the installed provisioning profile file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30558019)